# Using InteractJs with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I'm struggling to get the typings for interact into my typescript project.

The only type file I found for InteractJs was here: https://github.com/taye/interact.js/blob/master/interact.d.ts

So I can't install it using the standard npm @ type.

Instead,  I created an interact folder within node_modules/@types, and placed the above type file. I then tried to reference it from within my ts file, and the compiler still winges that:

> Cannot find type definition file for 'interact'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include your ts file that references interact?

Comment: I just solved it with a bit of a hack by putting : ```declare var interact: Function;``` at the top. The ts file is a few hundred lines, so best not to include it.